# Mongoose find documents where field = req.body.user

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a user schema and a post schema, wherein a user has many posts. I would like to return all posts that the user has on a route called '/post/dashboard'.

Here is my schemas:

```
let UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        default: null,
    },
    profile_pic: {
        type: String,
        default: '/img/profilepic.png',
    },
    posts: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Post'
    }
})
let PostSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
    }
    original_poster: {  
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    tags: {
        type: [String]
    }
})
```

So, for example something like:

```
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    Post.find({ original_poster: req.session.user }).then((posts) =>{
        res.send(JSON.stringify(posts));
    }) //where req.session.user is an id (the logged in user's object id or _id)
})
```

Essentially in sql syntax it might be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM POSTS WHERE ORIGINAL_POSTER = <req.session.user>
```

What is the proper way to return all posts by the req.session.user?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `original_poster` field represent a reference to User's model, If `req.session.user` is stored as a string you have to cast it to `objectID`:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

...

let userId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.session.user);
Post.find({ original_poster: userId }).then((posts) => {
    res.send(JSON.stringify(posts));
});
```